# Hitting time of Brownian motion with drift using Feynman-Kac

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, feynman-kac

I was studying this question from "A Practical Guide to Quantitative Finance Interviews" and was having some trouble understanding one solution. Please advise if misunderstood anything or if there is any reference paper I could turn to.

Here is the question:

*Suppose that X is a Brownian motion with no drift, i.e., dX(t) = dW(t). If X starts at 0, what is the probability that X hits 3 before hitting -5? What if X has drift m, i.e., dX(t)=mdt+dW(t)?*

My question is only for the second half and here goes the solution (I'm simply copying from the book):

*When X has drift m, the process is no longer a martingale. Let P(t,x) be the probatility that the process hits 3 before hitting -5 when X=x at time t. Although X is no longer a martingale process, it is still a Markov process. So P(t,x)=P(x) is actually independent of t. Applying the Feynman-Kac equation, we have:
mP<sub>x</sub>(x)+1/2P<sub>xx</sub>(x)=0, boundary conditions:P(3)=1, P(-5)=0*

What I'm trying to figure out is how to construct and define the functions that serve as the bridge to connects the PDE and conditional expectation? Namely, Feynman-Kac goes as:

*If X is an Ito process such that dX(t)=$\beta$(t,X)dt+$\gamma$(t,X)dW and f(x) is a function of X. Define function V(t,x)=E[f(X<sub>T</sub>)|X<sub>t</sub>=x], then V(t,x) is a martingale process that satisfies the partial differential equation $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+\beta(t,x)\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}+\frac{1}{2}\gamma(t,x)\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2}=0$ and terminal condition V(T,x)=f(x).*

If P(x) is the V here, then how do we find and define f(x)?

Many thanks!

Comment: You will find a detailed account of this in the book Karatzas & Shreve, *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*.

Comment: See the Fokker-Plank equation.